# Extending extension with new actions

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm migrating from 6.2 to 7.6 and I'm struggling with an extension(A) that extends another extension (b) that extends News (A-->B-->News).  Everything is OK in 6.2 but not in 7.6.

I'm calling my action from Typoscript (lib.news.nextEvent)

```
lib.news.nextEvent < .related
nextEvent  {
    switchableControllerActions {
          News {
            1 = nextEventList
          }
    }

    settings {
        startingpoint = 123
        limit = 15

    link {
            skipControllerAndAction = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I have this error

```
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 201812181555070cca4167 - {"exception":"exception 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Exception\\NoSuchActionException' with message 'An action \"nextEventListAction\" does not exist in controller \"Roquin\\RoqNewsevent\\Controller\\EventController\"
```

TypoScript\setup.txt

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        Roquin\RoqNewsevent\Controller\EventController {
            className = QcMedia\QmNewsExtended\Controller\NewsExtendedController
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller i have (not the full actual class)

```
NewsExtendedController.php

use Roquin\RoqNewsevent\Controller\EventController;

class NewsExtendedController extends EventController

public function nextEventListAction(array $overwriteDemand = NULL)
```

Can someone give me a hint about that error?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of roq_newsevent are you using? [3.1.1](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/roq_newsevent/) form TYPO3 extension repository? Or a fork [visol/ext-roq_newsevent](https://github.com/visol/ext-roq_newsevent) from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of `roq_newsevent` you are use, the namespace is different in case:

TYPO3 Extension Repository [3.1.1](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/roq_newsevent/):

```
ROQUIN\RoqNewsevent\Controller
```

Fork from [visol/ext-roq_newsevent](https://github.com/visol/ext-roq_newsevent) 3.3.0:

```
Roquin\RoqNewsevent\Controller
```

This should not be a problem, but i am not sure about the implementation in TYPO3.

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        ROQUIN\RoqNewsevent\Controller\EventController {
            className = QcMedia\QmNewsExtended\Controller\NewsExtendedController
        }
    }
}
```

You can try use [XCLASS](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/7.6/ApiOverview/Xclasses/) in `ext_localconf.php` instead of TypoScript `config.tx_extbase.XXX`

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['ROQUIN\\RoqNewsevent\\Controller\\EventController'] = [
   'className' => 'QcMedia\\QmNewsExtended\\Controller\\NewsExtendedController'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing more to do apart extending the controller class and declaring the extended controller className in Typo3 setup which you did correctly.

If your class name QcMedia\QmNewsExtended\Controller\NewsExtendedController is correct and the extension QmNewsExtended is correctly installed, there might be an issue with your caches. Did you clear all caches including the autoload rebuild?

Comment: I delete all the content of typo3Temp and my class QcMedia\QmNewsExtended\Controller\NewsExtendedController is writtent in autoload_classmap.php.  My class Roquin\RoqNewsevent\Controller\EventController is not in autoload_classmap.php.  How can I autoload it?

Comment: After uninstalling and installing the extension the classes are back in autoload_classmap.php but I get the same error.